# Test Report Generation with Junit

Tags: unit-testing, logging, junit, reporting, junit5

I want to do logging and Test Report Generation with Junit. Logging to a txt file i can achieve using the java logger. To achieve the reporting part, As of Junit 4 there is no such feature. I have heard with Junit 5 it should be possible to generate the test report. Could someone throw some light in to this with their experience of report generation with Junit?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in [How to create an HTML report for JUnit 5 tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444908/how-to-create-an-html-report-for-junit-5-tests/39455463#39455463), the JUnit Platform Gradle Plugin and `ConsoleLauncher` already generate JUnit 4 style XML reports.

This is done by the [XmlReportWriter](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/junit-platform-console/src/main/java/org/junit/platform/console/tasks/XmlReportWriter.java) which is used by the [XmlReportsWritingListener](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/junit-platform-console/src/main/java/org/junit/platform/console/tasks/XmlReportsWritingListener.java). The latter is simply an implementation of `TestExecutionListener`.

So, if you want to generate custom reports, you can simply implement your own `TestExecutionListener` and take inspiration from the `XmlReportWriter` and `XmlReportsWritingListener`.

Regards,

Sam (*Core JUnit 5 committer*)

Answer (score 0):

If your project is maven bases, then why not try surefire plugin.
doc [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-mojo.html) - http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-mojo.html