# Junit5 html report generation

Tags: jenkins, gradle, build.gradle, junit5

Recently migrated from JUnit4 to JUnit5. As per the current gradle settings I no longer see HTML reports getting generated. Have googled but could find a way to generate these reports. Has anyone tried to generate HTML reports of test under JUnit5?

When I run the test under JUnit5, I see a binary folder with files

```
output.bin
output.bin.idx
results.bin
```

And hence resultant `html` report is not generated.

`gradle.build` code that helps club results from the `test` task in all subprojects

```
task testReport(type: TestReport) {
  destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/allTests")
  reportOn subprojects*.test

  doLast {
      println "Test reports for all test complete $env"
  }
}
```

If there is need for more code to share, please let me know.

Comment: please share more details: post-build step you're using (html publisher / junit / xunit). pipeline? regular build? & etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML report for JUnit 5 tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444908/how-to-create-an-html-report-for-junit-5-tests)

Comment: @sam-brannen Nope. Thats completely different. It uses Ant.

Comment: @Vano Added code to show how HTML report is getting generated.

Comment: @java_dude I actually was not asking a question. The "?" was added automatically by Stack Overflow when I attempted to close this issue as a _duplicate_. So I apologize if you were confused by the "?".

Comment: In my attempt to close the issue, I was actually emphatically stating that it is a duplicate. My answer on the linked issue explains everything. So I suggest that you go back and read my response in detail.

Comment: The linked issue is not about Ant. The only thing about Ant is the fact that you can use Ant as an interim solution for generating HTML reports until the Gradle team officially takes over development of the JUnit Platform Gradle plugin.

Comment: Working on resolving this.

Comment: I aren't have much experience in gradle, Hope this related answer helps your question. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/39455463/3044557