# Configuration for Gradle 4.7 to generate the HTML report for JUnit 5 tests

Tags: gradle, junit, build.gradle, junit5

I have an app based as follows:

- `Spring Framework` 5.0.4.RELEASE
- `Gradle` **4.7** - multimodule project configured through
- `JUnit` 5.1.1

The configuration about Gradle with JUnit is in the `build.gradle` file located in the root module:

```
...
subprojects {

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'

    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    ext {
      ...
      junitVersion = '5.1.1'
      ...
    }

    dependencies {

       ...

       //Testing
       ...
       testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitVersion"
       testCompile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:$junitVersion";
       testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junitVersion"
       ....

    }

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()      
    }

}

//This location is mandatory
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {      
        classpath "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.1.0"
    }

}
```

Through `Jenkins` I execute:

- `gradle :thymeleaf-02-infrastructure:test --parallel`
- and with `Publish JUnit test result report` is configured to `thymeleaf-02-infrastructure/build/test-results/junit-platform/*.xml`

From above all work fine, I can see in `Jenkins` the `@Test` passed but `Gradle` does not generate the `report` directory with the expected `html` file.

Even if directly the `gradle :thymeleaf-02-infrastructure:test --parallel` command is executed in the terminal, all work (tests passe), but `Gradle` does not generate the `report` directory with the expected `html` file.

I already have read these links:

- [How to use JUnit 5 with Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429751/how-to-use-junit-5-with-gradle)
- [How to create an HTML report for JUnit 5 tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444908/how-to-create-an-html-report-for-junit-5-tests)

And well I am using

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()      
}
```

*and* `Gradle` is *>4.6*, **4.7**, so what is missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the `org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin` because it disables the standard `test` task by default.

Comment: I tried and sadly it does not work. I can remember I just did do an upgrade from `4.7-rc-2` (there it works) to `4.7`. Not sure was is wrong ... And I tried again with `4.7-rc-2` and **now** does not work too... I did do an upgrade about `JUnit` from `5.1.0` to `5.1.1`

Comment: Can you post a complete sample project?

Comment: No, because is huge, but I am going to create one minimum based in multi modules too, thus it to be shared through Github ....

Comment: Something I did realize is that neither `org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin` nor `org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin` are not mentioned in your `Gradle User Guide` link shared ... I will try if it would be the reason ... perhaps both should be not there

Comment: Indeed, I missed that. I've updated my response accordingly.

Comment: Just curious why that plugin has not been removed in the `4.7.x` series ...

Comment: From Gradle‘s perspective, it‘s a third-party plugin. The Junit team will deprecate it in 5.2 and discontinue it with 5.3.